# Unable to use java compiler even after installing

Tags: java, compiler

I wanted to use the JDK version 8.0 for NetBeans, so I uninstalled my latest version of JDK 11.0 by using these commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac
```

But when I installed the 8.0 version and went to verify the installation I got the following response:

```
/usr/bin/javac: 4: .: Can't open /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh
```

I tried reinstalling JDK 11.0 again and both compilers were present:

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Can someone please help in sorting this issue??

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Java problem, it's a NetBeans problem. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge netbeans   
sudo apt install netbeans
```

[image: select Java Platform]
<sup>***Tools* -> *Options* -> *Java* -> *Nashorn*** tab -> select ***Java Platform***</sup>

You can edit the path to the Java executable by clicking the <kbd>Manage Platforms...</kbd> button in the above screenshot, and editing the field  after where it says *Platform Folder* which is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot.

[image: Java Platform Manager]